# How can i tell to my teacher that I had finished my homework? (I had done it in the past)

Tags: grammar

How can i tell to my teacher that I had finished my homework? (I had done it in the past)

Comment: Say ‘I have finished my homework’; the answer is right there. Is your question more complex than that? What kind of situation is this in?

Comment: Don't worry so much that your English might not be perfect! Unless you're applying for a job as an English teacher or a translator, most people will be understanding as long as you can communicate. Have a sense of humor about it. If you say something wrong and someone tells you that that means something impossible or silly, laugh along with them and learn for the next time.

Comment: I've edited the body of your question. I've removed everything.  The title didn't match the body.  The body of the question should state the question you are asking and give all details.  I removed everything in the body because it wasn't a question. This question needs work  You need to add what you think is the right answer and ***why***.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is more correctly stated "How can I tell my teacher that I have finished my homework? (I did it in the past.)" The answer is "I have finished my homework" or simply "I finished my homework."